# Configure SpringBoot security with Vue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I trying to configure a spring security to use with Rest so I create this file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().
                csrf().disable().
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login").failureForwardUrl("/login?erro")
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .and().httpBasic().disable();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider
                = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }
}
```

But When I try to access /login with wrong password and username the try to redirect to a default form login.

how can I disable this default form?

tks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the configuration of custom login

```
 .and()
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/login");
```

this line loginPage("/login") will tell spring security to override the default login page

checkout [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html#overriding-the-default-configure-httpsecurity-method)